# Issue with Azure Active Directory Integration with Google

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, google-directory-api, google-provisioning-api

I setup Azure Active Directory SSO with my Google Apps Domain, and I having issues setting up the Google Auto Account Provisioning. I hit enabled and configure 'auto account provisioning', and all I get is blank screen in a pop-up. I tried this the latest version of Chrome and IE.

I believe the expected behavior is a Google Login screen to finish the OAuth authorization based on the [setup tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-saas-google-apps-tutorial/).

I did confirm that I don't have any funky pop-up blockers, Google API provisioning is enable, and I am also logged into my Google account.

Has anyone got this work?